# XSL Counter over flat XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to maintain a sequence number counter over the following source XML snippet. The sequence number is in the target OBX.1 element. This is based on the elements NOS/POS/ROS in the source having data in them. In this example, since all 3 elements have data, the sequence 1,2,3 is generated in OBX.1's. However, if any of NOS/POS/ROS are empty then the corresponding OBX node should not be generated but the remaining elements should be in the right sequence. I can do this by by setting OBX.1 to:
count(preceding-sibling::ns1:NOS[string-length(.) > 0]|preceding-sibling::top:POS[string-length(.) > 0]) + 1 but it gets tedious when you have 15 such elements. Is there a better way to maintain this counter?

Source XML Snippet:

```
<ns1:HladtCollection xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/ReadAdtHistorical">
        <ns1:Hladt>
            <ns1:ADTMessageID>123</ns1:ADTMessageID>
            <ns1:ADTMessageType>ADD</ns1:ADTMessageType>
            <ns1:AccountNumber>3456</ns1:AccountNumber>
            <ns1:ArrivalDate>2016-03-22T11:45:12.220000000</ns1:ArrivalDate>
            <ns1:NOS>Test1</ns1:NOS>
            <ns1:POS>Test2</ns1:POS>
            <ns1:ROS>Test3</ns1:ROS>
        </ns1:Hladt>
</ns1:HladtCollection>
```

Target XML Snippet:

```
<ns1:OBX>
  <ns1:OBX.1>1</ns1:OBX.1>
  <ns1:OBX.2>ST</ns1:OBX.2>
  <ns1:OBX.3>
     <ns1:CE_OBS.1>
        <ns1:CM_OBS.1>122</ns1:CM_OBS.1>
     </ns1:CE_OBS.1>
  </ns1:OBX.3>
  <ns1:OBX.5>Test1</ns1:OBX.5>
</ns1:OBX>
<ns1:OBX>
  <ns1:OBX.1>2</ns1:OBX.1>
  <ns1:OBX.2>ST</ns1:OBX.2>
  <ns1:OBX.3>
     <ns1:CE_OBS.1>
        <ns1:CM_OBS.1>111</ns1:CM_OBS.1>
     </ns1:CE_OBS.1>
  </ns1:OBX.3>
  <ns1:OBX.5>Test2</ns1:OBX.5>
</ns1:OBX>
<ns1:OBX>
  <ns1:OBX.1>3</ns1:OBX.1>
  <ns1:OBX.2>ST</ns1:OBX.2>
  <ns1:OBX.3>
     <ns1:CE_OBS.1>
        <ns1:CM_OBS.1>222</ns1:CM_OBS.1>
     </ns1:CE_OBS.1>
  </ns1:OBX.3>
  <ns1:OBX.5>Test3</ns1:OBX.5>
</ns1:OBX>
```

Comment: I reduced the number of times I had to type the long expression to just once in an additional template  and just calling this template in each OBX.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were only selecting your `NOS`, `POS` or `ROS` elements if there were not empty, you could use the `position()` function, as this returns the position of the node in the selected node set, not the position in the hierarchy. For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="(ns1:NOS|ns1:POS|ns1:ROS)[. != '']">
    <ns1:OBX>
       <ns1:OBX.1><xsl:value-of select="position()" /> </ns1:OBX.1>
       <ns1:OBX.5><xsl:value-of select="." /></ns1:OBX.5>
    </ns1:OBX>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, you could use `xsl:number`

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns1:NOS|ns1:POS|ns1:ROS">
   <xsl:if test=". != ''">
      <ns1:OBX>
         <ns1:OBX.1><xsl:number count="ns1:NOS[. != '']|ns1:POS[. != '']|ns1:ROS[. != '']" /> </ns1:OBX.1>
          <ns1:OBX.5><xsl:value-of select="." /></ns1:OBX.5>
      </ns1:OBX>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks!, this is good to know. Unfortunately in this scenario the OBX.3 value is dependent if its a NOS/POS etc.